# Sending data from Flask to Java Server

Tags: java, python, json, post, flask

I'm not really familiar with engineering side of Python and Flask so I'd like to know the following-I have a Flask app which receives POST requests with json formatted data and apply them into a predictive model and gets outcome also as a json data. Here is the code to be more precisely:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import io
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fbprophet import Prophet

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/postjson', methods = ['POST'])

def postJsonHandler():

print (request.is_json)
content = request.get_json()

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(content, 'data')    
df.rename(columns={0 : 'ds', 1 : 'y'}, inplace=True)
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])

my_model = Prophet(interval_width=0.95, yearly_seasonality=False, daily_seasonality=False, weekly_seasonality=True)

df['y'] = np.log(df['y'])

my_model.fit(df)

future_dates = my_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=30)

forecast = my_model.predict(future_dates)

yhat=forecast.yhat
ser=np.exp(yhat)

df_upd=pd.DataFrame(ser[-30:])
df_upd.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

js=df_upd.to_dict(orient='split')
del js['index']
res=json.dumps(js)

print(res)

return 'JSON posted'


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 8090)
```

What should I exactly do to be able to send the outcome data of the model (res) to Java Server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it out.

Basically, what's needed to do in this situation is to use Response object and do something like this for sending the data back to server:

```
answer = Response(res, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```